# mixing mobile and desktop with the grid system

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap documentation states that grid columns should add up to twelve for a single horizontal block. More than that, and columns start stacking no matter the viewport. Then it goes on to give an example of mixing mobile and desktop:

[image]

So .col-md-8 and .col-md-4 add up to 12 and so they should remain on a single horizontal block. However, .col-xs-12 and .col-xs-6 do not add up to 12. My assumption here is that we mix xs and md because we want them both to appear on a single horizontal block for their respective devices. So wouldn't .col-xs-12 and .col-xs-6 stack? If not, why?

Comment: Yes they will stack on a mobile - .col-xs-12 will have a 100% width, while .col-xs-6 will have a width 50% of the container

Comment: @JamesKing then I am not understanding what they are accomplishing in this example. .col-md-8 and .col-md-4 will appear on one block on a desktop screen, whereas .col-xs-12 and .col-xs-6 will appear on two blocks on a phone resulting from stacking. Therefore, they will not look the same on the two devises. Wasn't the intention here to have them appear the same on mobile and desktop?

Comment: I think they're trying to illustrate how you can accomplish different layouts simply by altering the number of columns based on the screen size. You can see this if you read the code comments in the example at  http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid `<!-- Stack the columns on mobile by making one full-width and the other half-width -->`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xs-*` classes targets devices <768px while `md-*` classes target ≥992px.

so if you are on a phone (<768px) just look at the xs class and ignore the md class. you will have 12  + 6, since each row only has 12 columns your divs should look like this:

```
------------  <-- xs-12
------        <-- xs-6
```